# argument of type "void (Biometria::*)(char *idSensor, GRCAP_FINGER_EVENTS event)" is incompatible with parameter of type "GRCAP_STATUS_EVENT_PROC *"

Tags: c++, dll, wrapper, dllimport

I need to implement some callback functions from a external DLL, but I can't find a way to put it inside my class.

The DLL method:

```
//CALLBACK functions
typedef void CALLBACK GRCAP_STATUS_EVENT_PROC(char* idSensor, GRCAP_STATUS_EVENTS event);
DLLIMPORT
GrCapInitialize(GRCAP_STATUS_EVENT_PROC *StatusEventHandler);
```

My class:

```
Class Biometria {
public
void StatusEventHandler(char* idSensor, GRCAP_STATUS_EVENTS event);
}

// Consumes data from a status event.
void Biometria::StatusEventHandler(char* idSensor, GRCAP_STATUS_EVENTS event) {
    // Signaling that a status event occurred.
    if (event == GR_PLUG) {
        // Start capturing from plugged sensor.
        GrCapStartCapture(idSensor, myFingerCallBack, myImageCallBack);
    }
    else if (event == GR_UNPLUG) {
        // Stop capturing from unplugged sensor
        GrCapStopCapture(idSensor);
    }
}
```

The point where I get the error:

```
int Biometria::Initialize() {
    //some code
    return GrCapInitialize(&Biometria::StatusEventHandler);
}
```

I already tried with static method without success.

Comment: You can't use a member function pointer for C-like function callbacks. A static member function should work though.

Comment: melak47, when I set my method to static I get this error: a storage class may not be specified here

Comment: the `static` keyword only goes on the declaration, not the definition

Comment: You totally solved it!! I past the last 2 days trying to solve this. Thanks man!!

Comment: As I can't answer my own question yet I'll leave it here for now... Solved after changing method declaration to:

    static GRCAP_STATUS_EVENT_PROC StatusEventHandler;

Answer (score 0):

Solved after changing method declaration to:

```
static GRCAP_STATUS_EVENT_PROC StatusEventHandler;
```